# make text stay at bottom of grid bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

i tried to make a text position to bottom of grid,
i tried with position absolute but it didnt effect. what a way to solve the problem?

```
.row{
  position: relative;
}
.p{
  display: inline;
}
```

heres the link for the problem

https://jsfiddle.net/ntLonmc4/5/

thank for your help

Comment: Your html is not structured properly. The ul with class inline is inside a li element not the row element.

Comment: it can't be at the bottom of .row because your ul with class inline is inside li element which has position relative so the ul will be at the bottom of li not the .row

Comment: got update my jsfiddle, can u check it guys?

Comment: Describe "make text stay at bottom of grid" - What text, which grid, bottom relative to what element? This question, with the fiddle, is still unclear

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ntLonmc4/6/ sir, sorry for the unclear. i want to the paragraph inside class attribute stay at bottom line of the grid

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ntLonmc4/7/